# Why am I getting gulp-changed error?

Tags: react-native, gulp, gulp-changed

My gulpfile is below -

```
'use strict';

//dependencies
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-clean-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var changed = requrie('gulp-changed');
```

Error after runnning gulp. 
Error is for `var changed = requrie('gulp-changed');` -

```
ReferenceError: requrie is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/lap1/Desktop/ReactJS/react- 
test/gulpfile.js:9:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at execute (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp- 
cli/lib/versioned/^3.7.0/index.js:28:18)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp- 
cli/index.js:175:63)
```

Gulp version - `3.9.1`
React native version - `2.0.1`
I have installed all the dependencies both globally and for the project alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there iss a spelling mistake

Replace this

```
var changed = requrie('gulp-changed');
```

by

```
var changed = require('gulp-changed');
```